# how to apply filter only on outlook messages using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

The following code which get all uncategorised items from outlook however it returns all the items including appointments and meetings. I need a code which returns only messages which are not categorised.

```
Sub NullCategoryRestriction() 
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder 
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items 
    Dim Filter As String 

    'DASL Filter can test for null property. 
    'This will return all items that have no category. 
    Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & _ 
     "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords" & _ 
     Chr(34) & " is null" 
    Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 
    Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter) 
    Debug.Print oItems.Count 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [MessageClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867813.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property check to the filter as well. The property returns a string representing the message class for the Outlook item.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & _
     "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords" & _
     Chr(34) & " is null"

Set ml = ml.Items.Restrict(Filter)

For i = ml.Count To 1 Step -1

      If TypeOf ml(i) Is MailItem Then

      End if

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be no noticeable gain in efficiency but you could apply a second restrict rather than checking each item with `If TypeOf ml(i) Is MailItem Then`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NullCategoryRestriction_MailItems()

    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oItems As Items
    Dim ml As Items
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim oFilter As String
    Dim oFilter2 As String
    
    Debug.Print
    'DASL Filter can test for null property.
    'This will return all items that have no category.
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Search-and-Filter/filter-items-that-do-not-have-categories
    oFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & _
      "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords" & _
      Chr(34) & " is null"
    Debug.Print " " & oFilter
    
    Set oFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict(oFilter)
    Debug.Print "   oItems.Count: " & oItems.Count
    
    'This will return mailitems
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes
    oFilter2 = "[MessageClass] = 'IPM.Note'"
    Debug.Print " " & oFilter2

    Set ml = oItems.Restrict(oFilter2)
    Debug.Print "   ml.Count: " & ml.Count
    
    For i = ml.Count To 1 Step -1
        ' If TypeOf ml(i) Is mailItem Then
            Debug.Print ml(i).MessageClass & ": " & ml(i).subject
        'End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

The TypeOf test is no longer necessary.